Override kafka properies with spring boot
I try to securize my spring boot application by crypting my kafka properties
For example, to run my jar i do this :
java -jar myjar.jar --spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers='encryptedServer' --spring.kafka.properties.ssl.keystore.password='encryptedKeystore'  --spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.password='encryptedTruststore'

And i want decrypt my properties during my app launching
I found something on the web and i did that
public class DecoderEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private static final List<String> ENCODED_PASSWORD = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
        add("spring.kafka.properties.ssl.keystore.password");
        add("spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.password");
    }};
    
    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        for (String property : ENCODED_PASSWORD) {
            String encodedPassword = environment.getProperty(property);
            if (encodedPassword != null) {
                try {
                    String decodedPassword = myDecrypt(encodedPassword);
                    environment.getSystemProperties().put(property, decodedPassword);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //TODO
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And added "org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.my.app.DecoderEnvironmentPostProcessor" in the file src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories
The code decrypts well my properties, but when I launch my application i have an error in this class :
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        try {
            Optional<LocalConfig> optionalLocalConfig = localConfigManager.loadConfig();
            this.registrar = registrar;

                MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, JsonNode> endpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
// endpoint setId,setTopics etc ..
                
             registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint); 

        } catch (KafkaException e) {
            //TODO
        }
    }

the line "registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint)" gives the error
2024-04-18 17:52:57,089 ERROR : configureKafkaListeners Error while configuring kafka listeners, service will be restarted
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
....
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: encryptedServer
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:59)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:728)
  ... 162 common frames omitted

but bootstrap.servers should be decryptedServer not encrytedServer

I found how to do
In configureKafkaListeners i added :
endpoint.setConsumerProperties(decryptEncryptedProperties());
And
public Properties decryptEncryptedProperties() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    String bootstrapServers = environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
    bootstrapServers = mydecrypt(bootstrapServers);
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);


    String keystorePassword = environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.properties.ssl.keystore.password");
    keystorePassword = mydecrypt(keystorePassword);
    properties.put("ssl.keystore.password", keystorePassword);


    String truststorePassword = environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.password");
    truststorePassword = mydecrypt(truststorePassword);
    properties.put("ssl.truststore.password", truststorePassword);


    return properties;
}

